# Improve the consistency of aruco pose

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

What is the best way to improve the consistency of the pose estimation of an aruco marker. Even when the camera and marker are stationary I am getting a lot of variation in my reading for the rotation about the y axis. I have moved from a 6x6 marker to a 7x7 marker.
I'm using 100mm marker sizes and an intel realsense camera running at 30fps in 1920x1080. This happens when the distance between the marker and camera is both large and small.

Comment: the number of bits in the marker don't matter. go with 4x4 for best identification results. -- try all the edge refinement methods. some cost more, but are more stable. -- it is a physical fact that results will get worse the smaller the marker appears. larger marker, more resolution, more optical zoom. pick whatever's doable.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz. I added april tag corner refinement and the pose is much for stable. However, to increase the speed I would like to change the detection mode to fast but DM_FAST isn't showing as an option when I  type out the line 
 parameters.DetectionMode = cv2.aruco.